# Make website case insensitive with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

This is what my .htaccess currently has

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

Options -Indexes
```

As it is right now, website.com/jobs works, while website.com/Jobs does not.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
CheckSpelling On
CheckCaseOnly On
Options -Indexes
```

I went ahead and made my .htaccess contain the following and my website now gives a 500 Internal Error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why would one want to make something simple as a URL case insensitive? What about the collisions with file systems which usually _are_ case sensitive on http servers? This only leads to confusion and does not really improve anything, I'd say...

Comment: My friend went ahead and bought business cards for his company. The only issue is that his business cards say website.com/Jobs and he didn't check to see if it worked yet. So I'm trying to figure it out for him @arkascha

Comment: Is `mod_speling` module loaded in Apache config?

Comment: @anubhava I'm not sure. As I'm using a hosting service

Comment: You will need to get access to your error.log and see what is causing 500 error. I suspect `mod_speling` is not loaded

Comment: I was just told by tech support that mod_speling is not enabled. The main problem is /Jobs to /jobs. is there anyway to do that without mod_speling?

Comment: @ConfusedLife123 If that is all the issue, then just define a simple, single rewrite rule forwarding requests from `/Jobs` to `/jobs`. That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was just told by tech support that mod_speling is not enabled. The main problem is /Jobs to /jobs. is there anyway to do that without mod_speling?

You can do:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

# handle Jobs => jobs
RewriteRule ^Jobs/?$ /jobs [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use case-insensitive check in rewriteRule

> Use of the [NC] flag causes the RewriteRule to be matched in a
>   case-insensitive manner. That is, it doesn't care whether letters
>   appear as upper-case or lower-case in the matched URI.

so maybe

```
RewriteRule ^[Ww](.*)$ $1.php   [NC]
```

will work

Comment: I went and tried it with the [NC] tag. It didn't work with and without the checkspelling and checkcase entries

Comment: ok in that case, I think you need to add case insensitive regex in condition, please see my updated answer. I am not sure if the above rule is correct but the concept will work for you

Comment: This is what I have now http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=UeWmcpS5 . That gives me a 500 internal server. When I do it without the Checkspelling stuff, website.com/jobs and website.com/Jobs are not found. but website.com still loads fine

Comment: ok i noticed you have CheckSpelling there, do you have mod_spelling enabled ? and AllowOverride All in httpd.conf ?

Comment: Well, I'm using DreamHost as my host. So I wouldn't be able to tell you that for sure. Is there a way to find out? I'm gonna ask tech support right now

Comment: I was just told by tech support that mod_speling is not enabled